# Big tikzpicture on resized page creates empty page

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to get two big tikz pictures onto a resized page. If the picture becomes too big, then latex will insert an empty page and move the picture to the second one. How do I get rid of this empty page? As far as I understood the problem is the overfull vbox.

Here is a minimal (not) working environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    
    \pdfpagewidth=1000mm \pdfpageheight=800mm
    
        \newgeometry{left=0cm, top=0cm, textwidth=21.5cm} %textwidth was set until linebreaks were as wanted
        
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw [thick] (-23.392,-16.32) node {} rectangle (26.112,-68.544) node (v1) {};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        
        \restoregeometry
        
    \newpage
    \pdfpagewidth=700mm \pdfpageheight=400mm
    
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw [thick] (-23.392,-16.32) node {} rectangle (26.112,-20.544) node (v1) {};
        \end{tikzpicture}

    \newpage
    \pdfpagewidth=210mm \pdfpageheight=297mm
    
    Normal pages here

\end{document}
```

The first page is empty and the tikzpicture is on the second page.

Setting the first page in \geometry (as Ivan suggested) solves the problem, but cause the text on the normal A4 page to look bad.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=0cm, top=0cm,textwidth=21.5cm,paperwidth=1000mm,paperheight=800mm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [thick] (-23.392,-16.32) node {} rectangle (26.112,-68.544) node (v1) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \restoregeometry
    \pdfpagewidth=700mm \pdfpageheight=400mm
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [thick] (-23.392,-16.32) node {} rectangle (26.112,-20.544) node (v1) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \newpage
    \pdfpagewidth=210mm \pdfpageheight=297mm \textwidth=150mm
    
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   
    

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=0cm, top=0cm,textwidth=21.5cm}

\begin{document}

 \pdfpagewidth=1000mm \pdfpageheight=800mm
  
 \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
 \draw [thick] (-23.392,-16.32) node {} rectangle (26.112,-68.544) node (v1) {};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 
 \restoregeometry
 \pdfpagewidth=700mm \pdfpageheight=400mm
 
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw [thick] (-23.392,-16.32) node {} rectangle (26.112,-20.544) node (v1) {};
 \end{tikzpicture}

\newgeometry{textwidth=150mm} 
 \pdfpagewidth=210mm \pdfpageheight=297mm 
 
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   
 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This prevents the empty page, but causes new problems with text wrapping on the third page. I added an example to my question.

Comment: Try using the `pass` option: `\usepackage[pass]{geometry}`. And then `\newgeometry{textwidth=15cm}` 
`\pdfpagewidth=210mm \pdfpageheight=297mm`

Comment: Can you add this to your MWE? When I tried it, it went back to having an empty page at the beginning.

Comment: You should use `\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]` for the first picture. With this you can do without the `pass` option. You will also need to reposition the tikz picture. I edited my answer.

Comment: [Overlay] solved it! Thanks